# Output mysql data to csv/txt file using php script

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to output `mysql` columns to `txt`-file using `php` script, the query works fine on `mysql` but fails on `php`. When clicked on the button the function returns `Internal Server error`.

```
function RsyncFTPAction() {
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT("sshpass -p ""Password""  rsync   -avvtzh -e  ""ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no""  --log-file=""/home/toor/rsync2.log""",   login,"@", ftp_addr, " :", camera_name,"/",    "/",'home',"/",login, "/", camera_name)
FROM inteliviz.cameras order by id INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/wptitles2.csv' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";
        $result = $conn->Execute($sql);
        if(!$result) {
            print $conn -> ErrorMsg(); ;
            exit;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your quotes - or easier.. switch to single quotes, and escape them (there's less of them!)

```
$sql = 'SELECT CONCAT("sshpass -p ""Password""  rsync   -avvtzh -e  ""ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no""  --log-file=""/home/toor/rsync2.log""",   login,"@", ftp_addr, " :", camera_name,"/",    "/",`'home`',"/",login, "/", camera_name)
FROM inteliviz.cameras order by id INTO OUTFILE \'/tmp/wptitles2.csv\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\'';
```

Comment: I can't see, that you escaped the quotes

Comment: ..The single quotes are escaped, rather than the double ones.

Comment: This will still end up in a parse error. For example here: `,'home`

Comment: Ah yes, Missed one, I gave him the correct answer though, not all SO is meant to be copy and paste :)